# Control datatype assignment for auto generated code

Tags: c#, dotconnect

I am using [DotConnect by Devart](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/) Oracle Edition Professional 8.4.215.0 to access tables in an Oracle database.  I'm running into an issue where the auto generated code is interpreting NUMBER(3,0) data type as a boolean.  I intended it to be values from 0 to 9.

Is there a way to force the auto generated code construction to assign these as integers rather than boolean?

**Edit**

I manually changed them in the Designer.cs file and it seems to be working without a hitch, but I would prefer not editing this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are using Database-First approach (model is generated basing on a predefined database), aren't you?
2. Default mapping for Database-First approach can be customized in the following way:

   - via the Tools > Options > Servers' Options > Oracle menu (applied only for Entity Developer, *.edml)
   - using the Number Mappings connection string parameter (applied only for EDM Wizard, *.edmx)

We recommend you to use Entity Developer (the Devart Entity Model item, *.edml) instead of EDM Designer (the ADO.NET Entity Data Model item, *.edmx) because it is adjusted for working with Oracle and has an advanced functionality: http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/ed-vs-edm.html .

Does this help?

Comment: 1. Yes I have a database already in use that I'm coding for (and I don't have DBA rights).  2.  which Tools menu are you referring to?  I can't find the path suggested in VS2010.  I'm using http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/ professional edition 8.4.215.0.

Comment: 2.1. You are using Entity Developer (the Devart Entity Model item, *.edml), aren't you? 2.2. a) Entity Developer embedded in VS2010: Tools > Entity Developer > Options > Servers' Options > Oracle menu 2.2. b) Entity Developer as a separate tool: Tools > Options > Servers' Options > Oracle menu

Comment: Also please take into account that mapping customizations will be applied only for the newly created models (or if you recreate entities in CSDL basing on SSDL in an existing model).

Comment: Ok, I found it.  Thank you.